# How to find out why rails server hangs at 100%?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, gdb

Can someone think of a way to find out where our rails production server hangs? Its CPU is at 99% so I assume it gets lost in a while/for/each loop. Unfortunately we can't find a candidate loop.

The problem does not occur in development and our test suit now has 100% code coverage.

We were already attaching to Ruby via gdb, but didn't know where to go from there.
Any ideas?

Comment: another possibility is memory leaks!

Comment: thanks, memory usage is constant at ~24.5%,  before and after the server freezes.

Comment: unfortunately the problem occurs only once in every hundred thousand requests. of course we could refeed all those requests and try to find out which one is causing the problem but maybe there is a simpler way.

Comment: What about performance tests on development server? Use those dangerous requests that crash your production server.

Comment: have you tried using new relic?

Comment: thanks for the "new relic" hint! you should make that into an answer so that I can upvote.  it seems like monitoring applications is part of their pro offer, will be interesting to see if something is revealed once the application shows up in the dashboard.

Comment: this might be related to http://serverfault.com/questions/447065/why-is-my-rails-application-hanging

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you have attached with gdb to the busy looping process then call `rb_backtrace` from gdb:

```
> call rb_backtrace()
```

The output from `rb_backtrace` will be similar to a crash report, and the output will go to your log files similar to a standard Ruby error backtrace.

From there you should hopefully already be a step closer to the solution since you will see where in your Ruby code the process is stuck.

You can check out some more tips here:
http://isotope11.com/blog/getting-a-ruby-backtrace-from-gnu-debugger

Comment: !! At those people who down-voted or voted to close this question: if it is your plan to destroy the community you're really succeeding. many of our developer friends are already really angry about the new attitude over here. What would have been the point of closing this question and preventing Casper from kindly helping me and others with this problem??

Answer (score 1):

This is not a clean solution but at least the following resolved the problem for us:  we migrated to the 'thin' webserver and removed 'devise'.

Comment: I am having a similar problem and figured it had to be Devise.  The problem didn't exist before we dropped it in and it is now hanging our app in development mode after ~10+ page refreshes.  It disappears after we remove Devise.

I guess we have to roll our own authentication system.