# Ruby on rails website retains long running processes and is hanging, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when viewing linux processes with TOP, I will see 5 or 6 long-running ruby processes, and the website becomes unresponsive.

e.g.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND   
 6010 ec2-user  20   0  452m 113m 8724 S 16.0 11.5   0:46.91 ruby                                                  
 6044 ec2-user  20   0  452m 115m 8780 S 15.3 11.6   0:44.89 ruby                                                  
 6018 ec2-user  20   0  452m 114m 8724 S 15.0 11.6   0:46.11 ruby                                                  
 6054 ec2-user  20   0  452m 114m 8780 S 14.6 11.6   0:44.74 ruby                                                  
 6026 ec2-user  20   0  452m 114m 8724 S 14.3 11.5   0:45.60 ruby                                                  
 6036 ec2-user  20   0  448m 112m 6568 S 14.3 11.3   0:45.33 ruby                                                  
 2943 ec2-user  39  19  570m  12m 6728 S  8.0  1.2   2:05.32 PassengerAgent                                        
 6033 postgres  20   0  228m  12m 9696 S  1.3  1.2   0:02.30 postmaster                                            
 5855 ec2-user  20   0 15320 2180 1860 R  0.3  0.2   0:01.22 top
```

After restarting the server and restarting passenger ( bundle exec passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -d -e production ) the website will work, and in TOP I see ruby processes quickly coming and going. But very soon they stop "going", and the website becomes unresponsive.

I believe that when this starts happening, the passenger log starts to show "Returning HTTP 503 due to: Request queue full (configured max. size: 100)"

This is a pretty old website, which I did not build, but it has run error free for a long time and has developed this behavior in just the last 24 hrs.

Comment: Long-running processes are not the problem. Because that is what servers do, you start them and they running until stopped. I would suggest analyzing the log file for errors or long-running database queries. Or you could use tools like NewRelic, Sentry, or Skylight to find slow requests or slow endpoints. My first guess would be that the database has reached a tipping point and that there is a specific complex query that just takes too long because of the growing data in the database.

Comment: There isn't any table with more than 1200 records in the db, and no CMS changes were made recently. There's no e.g. watchdog table that could have grown enormous.  I don't see any large tables outside the public schema either. Of course there is no logging set up for the db. I will have to figure out how to do that.

Comment: a couple of things: 1) what database are you using, 2) have you done any patches or updates recently?

Comment: database is postgres, nothing at all has been done recently to the ec-2 instance, not even a reboot, before the malfunction began. If I just stop passenger, the long-running ruby processes and passengerAgent go away. Then after starting passenger again, I get a single ruby process with like 99% cpu, but it does manage to finish and serve up the page. Then after a few minutes and page  loads, we're back to where we started. I feel like the DB is not at fault, since it doesn't need restarting to get back to the nominal condition.

Comment: This is precisely what application performance monitoring is for. If you don't know what transactions are happening on your server then you won't figure this out. You need logging. You need monitoring. You need something like [New Relic](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/ruby-agent/getting-started/introduction-new-relic-ruby/).

Comment: The combined CPU usage of those Ruby processes is pretty much 100%. Something is making them busy with something. Is your website being DDOSed? Other alternatives is some data processing section in the code is stuck in a busy loop. When that happens Passenger will give a new request to the next free Ruby process. Once you run out of free instances, the request queue becomes full. In summary: you have a busy loop or DDOS problem.

Comment: @Casper that pretty exactly describes what's happening I think. I had moved the dns to Cloudflare but it's not showing any malicious activity, and the requests are pretty low, maybe 2.5k in 24 hrs.  The thing is, I don't see any part of the application that initially fails, i.e. the thing that's stuck in a loop. it's really just a one-pager, everything looks good until it doesn't load at all  due to the queueing.  Probably performance monitoring is in order, but i'm in the process of building the site's replacement with remix.run, and this site is ROR 3, which I know nothing about.

Comment: There are ways to attach a debugger to a running process and try to peek at what it's doing. I'll post a link to an old question from 2013, perhaps it helps. You can also Google something like "ruby gdb attach process print backtrace". https://stackoverflow.com/a/14788422/823617